# Is it possible to get the current page data after re-ordering in Material-Table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I need to get the current page data even after sorting. I can get the current page data after pagination changes, but not after sorting. Is this possible? `onOrderChange` returns the column id and direction only.

Is there a method that returns the sorted array?

```
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);

const currentPageItems = useMemo(() => removeData.slice(currentPage * rowsPerPage, currentPage * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage),
    [removeData, currentPage, rowsPerPage]);

return (
    <MaterialTable
        data={remoteData}
        options={{
          pageSize: 5,
          pageSizeOptions: [5, 10, 25],
          sorting: true,
        }}
        onChangePage={setCurrentPage}
        onChangeRowsPerPage={setRowsPerPage}
    />
)
```

Comment: I added a [PR](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/pull/1166) to add the currently dispalyed data to onOrderChange. Hope this helps

Comment: thanks. I found I can access the data through the ref.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered I can access the sorted data via tableRef.

```
const tableRef = useRef(null);
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);

const sortedData = tableRef.current?.dataManager?.sortedData ?? [];

const currentPageItems = useMemo(() => sortedData.slice(currentPage * rowsPerPage, currentPage * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage),
    [removeData, currentPage, rowsPerPage]);

return (
    <MaterialTable
        tableRef={tableRef}
        data={remoteData}
        options={{
          pageSize: 5,
          pageSizeOptions: [5, 10, 25],
          sorting: true,
        }}
        onChangePage={setCurrentPage}
        onChangeRowsPerPage={setRowsPerPage}
    />
)
```

Update: as far as I understand this is not reliable but it may be something I'm doing. If I try to access the tableRef in an effect and log when changes are made, nothing happens. (tableRef hasn't changed)

```
useEffect(
    () => {
      tableRef.current?.dataManager?.sortedData &&
        console.log(tableRef.current.dataManager.sortedData);
    },
    [tableRef]
  );
```

Comment: *the tableRef solution is not reliable. Don't use

Comment: Can you describe or show some code where it is not reliable. Maybe that points to a deeper problem within the data structure?

Comment: Yes since the tableref is a reference to the table, that does not change since it's always the same table. Why don't you put the sortedData into the []? Btw are you using create react app with the ? Accessor?

Comment: Not using CRA. Do you mean as a dependency? [tableRef.current.dataManager.sortedData] ?

Comment: I guess if the reference never changes, then the new data will need to be returned every time?

Comment: Yes like this tableRef.current.dataManager.sortedData which should only trigger an update after the sort changed.

Comment: @Domino987b What do you think is the best way forward for this? Does it need added MT functionality, or is it possible with current api?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if someone else have the same issue:

```
tableRef.current.onQueryChange({page: 0, search: ''})
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm using like below it's work to change page dynamically by code:

```
tableRef.current.dataManager.changeCurrentPage(5).
let tableState = tableRef.current.dataManager.getRenderState();
tableRef.current.setState(tableState);
```

the getRenderState() will return a obj ,it provide all information of your table's state.